# Error Codeigniter missing argument

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

This my problem:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>   Message: Missing argument 1 for TokoSaya::user(), called in /var/www/html/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 360 and defined
>   Filename: controllers/tokosaya.php
>   Line Number: 32
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined variable: id
>   Filename: controllers/tokosaya.php
>   Line Number: 34
>
> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number:
>   ERROR: syntax error at or near "$" LINE 1: SELECT * FROM usr.persons WHERE id = $id ^
>   SELECT * FROM usr.persons WHERE id = $id
>   Filename: /var/www/html/models/m_user.php
>   Line Number: 18

This my controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class TokoSaya extends CI_Controller {

/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
 *  - or -  
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
 *  - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in 
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
 * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'html', 'file','string'));
    //$this->load->library('grocery_CRUD'); 
    //$this->load->model('view');
    $this->load->model('m_user');
    $this->load->model('amproker');
    //$this->data['modul'] = 'Admin';
}

function user($id)
{
    $data['user'] = $this->m_user->GetDetailUser($id);
    //$data['UserLogin'] = $this->m_user->GetUserLogin($data['user']->person)
    $data['menu'] = $this->amproker->CategoriesMenu(0,$h="");
    $data['page'] = 'user';
    $this->load->view('templates_user', $data);
}

}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

This is my models:

```
<?php 

/**
* 
*/
class M_User extends CI_Model
{

function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->library(array('My_phpmailer', 'encrypt'));
    }

function GetDetailUser($id)
{
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT t0.*, t1.username, t1.person FROM usr.persons t0 RIGHT JOIN usr.logins t1 ON t0.id = t1.person WHERE t1.person = $id");
            return $query->row();

}

//function GetUserLogin($user)
//{
    //$query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM usr.logins")
    //return $query->result();
//}

}

?>
```

Comment: How did you call your controller? make sure that you are passing user id in your URL. Ex. `http://localhost/..../tokosaya/user/{$id}`

Answer (score 0):

Working from the top of your errors...

Your method **user($id)** is expecting a parameter and apparently you are not providing it one.

So the way you have written this, you would need to provide this parameter on the url ie `localhost/tokosaya/user/1` where the 1 in this case would provide a value of 1 for $id in your user method.

But you will need to ensure this parameter is indeed an integer and put some thought into how to deal with an integer(id) which does not return a result etc...